# How to refer to different tables from one column?

Tags: mysql, database-design

i have following db design(kept just essential informations):

```
 TABLE monument
     PRIMARY KEY id
     name

 TABLE restorer
      PRIMARY KEY id 
      name

 TABLE project
      PRIMARY KEY id
      name

 TABLE restorer2project
     FOREIGN KEY restorer_id REFERENCES restorer(id),
     FOREIGN KEY project_id REFERENCES project(id)
     PRIMARY KEY (restorer_id, restoration_project_id)

 TABLE monument2project
     FOREIGN KEY monument_id  REFERENCES monument(id)
     FOREIGN KEY project_id REFERENCES project(id)
     PRIMARY KEY (monument_id, project_id)
```

Project can have many restorers and have many monuments.Also project can repeat in future with same relations, but different date.
I want to create table witch will store pictures.

```
 TABLE picture
      PRIMARY KEY id
      reference_to_different_tables
```

Is it possible  point to different tables from one column? 
if yes how?
Is this good design (fro me it is natural i can imagine to create more tables  with pictures)

Other approach is to have references to pictures from other tables, but then i will need some kind of mapping table, but not sure if it is also good design.

Comment: I would just add 3 columns in the `picture` table. `project_id` not nullable, `restorer_id` not nullable, and `monument_id` nullable

Comment: @CptMisery: one thing is that i would have to handle data integrity manualy, and other i think there should be more straightforward solution as this looks to me as not so unique design pattern to be sloved

Answer (score 0):

From database prespective you can't have a foreign referring to different tables.
It can refer to one table at a time.
There can be three solutions I can think of:

1. The best solution in my opinion is to have a parent table say `artifact` to `monument`, `restorer` and `project`. The later three tables will have primary key as foreign key from `artifact` table. This way you can have single column in picture table which will refer to `artifact` table.
2. Or you can specify multiple columns in `picture` table as suggested by @CptMisery in the comments.
3. Create multiple picture table for all of them. This is not considered as good solution.

If you are using any persistence framework than the first solution can solve dynamic query problem as well.